# Current location in swift iOS 9

Tags: dictionary, location

I've added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in plist and set it to YES and here is my code:

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    print(location)
    print(center)

}
```

But it still doesn't work. It just doesn't show anything. 
It looks like locationManager function is never called. It even doesn't print anything to log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it by adding:

```
 locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

and declaring locationManager as a class variable. `var locationManager:CLLocationManager!`